# Font Awesome 5 Crushing Site Performance

Tags: wordpress, performance, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Has anyone experienced poor site performance when including Font Awesome 5? The difference between including it and not is night and day, like, 15 seconds difference in page loading for me.

I'm adding the script from https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js and there are several other ajax calls going on (Wordpress site using Ajax Load More). But I can't see why performance would be so crummy. It's even preventing scrolling for several seconds.

Comment: Are you loading the script in the footer?

Answer (score 4):

The official response from Font Awesome was...

> You might consider switching to Web Fonts with CSS instead. https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css. That will probably get you running smoother. I'm not sure if you are using pseudo-elements but this is a very non-performant method (we warn of this in the docs).

Switching to the Web Fonts fixed my problem.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: This question refers to a much older version of FontAwesome than is currently published, back when they had a different domaine even. If you're looking to get started now, I would recommend beginning here: https://fontawesome.com/start

Answer (score 0):

You should try new version (v5.1.0): I had a major performance improvement on my side, and I came back to normal performances now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll upgrade and see how it goes!